# How do you remove unused arguments for shell command run in perl?

Tags: perl, bash

My script gets a bunch of values for various arguments from a text file and puts them into variables. Then, the following line is run to execute a shell command with the various options:

`cmd -a $a -b $b -c $c` ;

However, how should I deal with the case where some arguments are not defined? Say -c is optional and thus the user leaves it blank in the text file. Right now if the code runs it would do

```
$a = "foo";
$b = "bar"; 
$c = "";
`cmd -a $a -b $b -c $c ` ; # this evaluates to "cmd -a foo -b bar -c"
```

which gives an error since -c needs an argument. Without implementing if-statements to consider each possible case for variable definition, is there a clean way to deal with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `Getopt::Std` module?

Comment: The arguments are not sent directly to the perl script via the command line, rather a text file contains all the arguments. This isn't my code, I need to add this feature on it though since we'll be using optional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight:

1. You run a Perl script.
2. That Perl script gets or creates a bunch of options for a command line script.
3. You then use those options to run an executable.

I would put your options into a Perl hash and have it keyed by the command line parameter and the value would be the value of that command line parameter.

```
my %parameters;
$parameters{"-a"} = "foo";
$parameters{"-b"} = "bar";
$parameters{"-c"} = "";
```

Now, let's build the command to execute. I'll parse through the array via the [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) command. This will return all the keys to may `%parameters` hash in my loop:

```
my $command = "cmd";

for my $param ( sort keys %parameters ) {
    if ( $parameters{ $param } ) {
        $command .= " $param $parameters{$param}";
    }
}
```

Notice that if `$parameters{ $param } is blank or zero, it will not add that parameter/value pair to the command line you're executing. Now, we can execute the command. Use`system` if you don't need any value back from the command. Then check to make sure the execution works:

```
my $error = system "$command";
if ( $error ) {
    die qq(Error detected in running command "$command");
}
```

If it is possible for the parameters to be null, have spaces, or zero values, we have to take a slightly different tact:

```
my %parameters;
$parameters{"-a"} = "foo";
$parameters{"-b"} = "bar";
$parameters{"-c"} = undef;

my $command = "cmd";

for my $param ( sort keys %parameters ) {
    if ( defined $parameters{ $param } ) {
        $command .= qw/ $param "$parameters{$param}"/;
    }
}

my $error = system "$command";
if ( $error ) {
    die qq(Error detected in running command "$command");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

$a = ...;
$b = ...;
$c = ...;

my @cmd = 'cmd';
push @cmd, '-a' => $a if length($a);
push @cmd, '-b' => $b if length($b);
push @cmd, '-c' => $c if length($c);
my $cmd = shell_quote(@cmd);
`$cmd`
```

If argument order doesn't matter, it would make more sense to use a hash rather than separate variables.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my %args = (
   '-a' => ...,
   '-b' => ...,
   '-c' => ...,
);

my @cmd = ( 'cmd', map { $_ => $args{$_} } grep length($args{$_}), keys(%args) );
my $cmd = shell_quote(@cmd);
`$cmd`
```

Comment: `shell_quote` makes it so it doesn't fail if any of the args contains a space or another shell meta-character.

Answer (score 3):

You can use hash, and then filter out arguments with zero length,

```
my %arg = (
  a => $a,
  b => $b,
  c => $c,
);
my $cmd_args = 
  join " ", 
  map { "-$_ $arg{$_}" }
  grep { length $arg{$_} > 0 }
  sort keys %arg;

`cmd $cmd_args`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the various `Getopt` modules to read the command line and place the entries into variables. Typically, an option that takes an argument will also have a default defined, or it will have the variable be undefined if no argument is given.

When the perl file executes, it will fill out the variables, and then you can construct the command line from those arguments,  You can use logic like:

```
push @cmd, "mycmd";
push @cmd, "-a", $opta;
push @cmd, "-b", $optb;
push @cmd, "-c", $optc if defined $optc; # Possibly leave out defined.
system @cmd;
```